What makes the method of directly multiplying differential elements in a change of variables for double integrals incorrect?
When applying a change of variables in double integrals, the relation containing the Jacobian is as follows:
$\iint_D f(x, y) \, dx \, dy = \iint_R f(x(u, v), y(u, v)) \, |J| \, du \, dv $
where  is the Jacobian, which is the determinant of the matrix containing the partial derivatives as follows:
$J = \begin{vmatrix} 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}$
The Jacobian adjusts the change in the differential element  when transitioning from the variables  to the variables . Therefore, we multiply the differential element by the absolute value of the Jacobian  to correct the calculations and compute the integral correctly.

However, since $x$ and $y$ are functions of $u$ and $v$ , we should be able to compute the differential elements  and  using partial derivatives as follows:
$x = x(u, v)$
$y = y(u, v)$
Therefore:
$dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \, du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \, dv$
$dy = \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} , du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} , dv$
When multiplying these differential elements  and , we get:
$dx \, dy = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \, du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \, dv \right) \cdot \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \, du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \, dv \right)$
Expanding this expression, we get:
$dx \, dy = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \, du^2 + \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \, du \, dv + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \, dv \, du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \, dv^2$
But we notice that this expansion contains the terms $du^2$ and $dv^2$ , which have no significance in double integrals. This makes the result far from correct, unlike the result obtained using the method that relies on the Jacobian.
Could you please clarify the considerations that make this method incorrect?

This procedure is not rigorously defined. However if you want to apply a somewhat justified heuristic you must take into account that the multiplication of differentials is like a cross product - it is anticommutative. I.e. $du "\times"du = 0$ and $du"\times"dv = -dv"\times"du$

In fact it is not $dxdy$ but $dx \wedge dy$ (where $\wedge$ is the exterior product) and therefore
$$dx \wedge dy = \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \, du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \, dv \right) \wedge \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \, du + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \, dv \right) \\
=
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \, du\wedge du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \, du \wedge dv + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \, dv \wedge du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \, dv \wedge dv$$
Since $dv\wedge dv = du \wedge du = 0$ and $dv \wedge du = -du\wedge dv$ it is
$$dx \wedge dy =
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}  - \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \right) du \wedge dv = \det(J) \, du \wedge dv$$
You can look after integrating "differential forms".

We have computed the differential elements $dx$ and $dy$ in terms of the infinitesimal changes $du$ and $dv$  using the Total Differential Formula. We know that this relationship deals with scalar quantities, not vectorial ones, and therefore the results will also be scalar quantities.
Given this, why do we rely on the exterior product  instead of the ordinary product , when the quantities we are dealing with are scalar quantities?
